# Select and remove element on list with many term in Scala

Tags: scala, list

I'm using `scala` for my logic program. I created list inside list with 5 elements each, for example:

```
val aList = List(List(2,2,8,5,6),List(8,4,5,6,7),List(1,8,1,2,1))
//the child list could be more than 3
```

I'm trying to get rid of non-duplicate elements with the following code:

```
def f(xs: List[Int]) = xs match {
  case x0 :: x1 :: _ if x0 == x1 => Some(xs.takeWhile(_ == x0))
  case _ => None
}

val aSelected = aList.flatMap(f)
```

and the result is:

```
aSelected: List(List(2,2),List(1,1,1))
```

But the problem is I need to include 8 if it's head, and while 8 is tail, 8 should be included with this terms:

1. 8 in head will be included. ex: `List(8,4,5,6,7) => List(8,4)`
2. 8 is besides duplicated elements on the left.ex: `List(2,2,8,5,6) => List(2,2,8)`
3. 8 also the bridge for same value if it’s in between same numbers, so they could be included. ex. `List(1,8,1,2,1) => List(1,8,1)`

So for above example, the result should be:

```
aList = List(List(2,2,8),List(8,4),List(1,8,1))
```

This terms are a bit hard for me. Is there any possibilities to create code something like this?

Comment: Some questions: (1) if you had this: `List(2,3,2,4,5)` where there are duplicates but they are not adjacent to each other, should it appear on the final list? (2) If you had this: `List(2,2,5,3,3)` where there are two duplicates on the same list, should the output be `List(List(2,2), List(3,3))`, `List(List(2,2,3,3))` or `List(List(2,2))`?

Comment: The code you provided does not do what you say it does.

Comment: You can do it much more simply than the accepted answer by 1) replacing `==` with a different comparator function, which returns true if they're equal or one of them is 8, and 2) adding a special case in the pattern match for when it starts with 8.

Comment: Something like this? `case  8 :: x1 :: x2 :: _ if x1 == x2 => Some(xs.takeWhile(_ == x1))
      case  x0 :: 8 :: x2 :: _ if x0 == x2 => List(x0) ++ List(8) (xs.takeWhile(_ == x2)` @LuigiPlinge

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you want to happen with a list such as `List(8,4,4,1,2)`... whether you want List(8,4,4) or List(8,4) as result. I was thinking, try defining `def similar(a:Int, b:Int) = a == b || a ==8 || b == 8` then replace `==` in `f` with this, and see what happens. (I find ScalaFiddle good for trying out things like this)

Comment: oh ya, I forgot to add that case, let me edit my question. The result I want is `List(8,4,4)` if we the list is `List(8,4,4,5,6)` for example. Thank you @LuigiPlinge you are my best teacher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider list one after other. on each list take while number is 8 or head of the current List.

Consider the case when you get only 8 and also consider the case when you will have only one number.

when you have just 8. ignore if you do not have next element. If you have next element then return the List(8, thatNumber)

When you have a number other than 8 then ignore if there is not next element. If you have next element then continue.

Everytime you get a partial list of (duplicates and 8's) drop that list from the main list and continue with the rest of the list.

```
  def foo(list: List[List[Int]]): List[List[Int]] = {
    def helper(currentList: List[Int], result: List[List[Int]]): List[List[Int]] = currentList match {
      case Nil => result
      case xList if xList.nonEmpty =>
        val xs = currentList.takeWhile(p => p == 8 || p == currentList.head)
        xs match {
          case Nil => result
          case 8 :: _ =>
            currentList match {
              case Nil => result
              case 8 :: x :: _ => helper(currentList.drop(2), result ::: List(8 :: x :: Nil))
            }
          case a :: Nil =>
            result
          case as =>
            helper(currentList.drop(as.length), result ::: List(as))
        }
    }
    list.flatMap(helper(_, List.empty[List[Int]]))
  }
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> val result = foo(aList)
result: List[List[Int]] = List(List(2, 2, 8), List(8, 4), List(1, 8, 1))
```

Comment: OMG, I thought the answer would be yes, it is possible or no, it is not possible since I asked about probability. Bro you complete my answer. So many thanks for the result.

Comment: Of course it is possible. Scala is turing complete.